# 12.04 freezes, battery drain, and fan noise too loud

Tags: dell, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I've been using 12.04 for a few weeks now and there are some things I have noticed. I'm running Ubuntu on a Dell n5010 (15R), with 3GB RAM, Intel Core i3, Intel HD graphics and Ubuntu 64x bit.

My battery drains too fast, lasts less than an hour, while in Windows used to last 3:30. I also noticed that the battery capacity decreased in a week from 78% to 74%. I get my screen frozen sometimes at the Ubuntu start screen, the purple one, with 5 dots below the logo.

Also, fan noise increases randomly, sometimes without running anything on the background. Sometimes, the freezes occur when using the computer and it doesn't let me type anything or use the touchpad, my only choice, is to shutdown.

Is it that my computer does not support Ubuntu? These are serious issues with Ubuntu and are making me go back to windows 7, which I hate.

Comment: Some of these issues are symptomatic of high-CPU usage, or other issues.  Are you fully updated?  Do you have a CPU-monitor running?  (Are some of your problems caused by high-CPU/)

Comment: well, i dont have a cpu-monitor running, but the laptop is not highly used. I mean, is mostly used for web surfing, and video playback. I installed inkscape 2 days ago, and i cant use it without having some error but closing the program every 10 to 15 minutes